# After GC , the address of the object in memory be changed and why the object reference still valid?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

> Java objects are created in Heap and Heap is divided into three parts
>   or generations for sake of garbage collection in Java, these are
>   called as Young generation, Tenured or Old Generation and Perm Area of
>   heap.  New Generation is further divided into three parts known as
>   Eden space, Survivor 1 and Survivor 2 space. When an object first
>   created in heap its gets created in new generation inside Eden space
>   and after subsequent Minor Garbage collection if object survives its
>   gets moved to survivor 1 and then Survivor 2 before Major Garbage
>   collection moved that object to Old or tenured generation.

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/04/garbage-collection-in-java.html#ixzz2MeKK2gBA

So my question is that after these moving action , the address in memory should be changed and why the object reference still valid ?

Comment: A symbol in java is not just a pointer like in C. A symbol references to a lookup table, where there's more information stored about the object the symbol references. The symbol references get altered when the GC alters the position in java memory space.

Comment: @Konstantin I think the question is: how does it work internally, which is not uninteresting.

Comment: @assylias there are vast variety of JVMs and they might behave differently, so this question is totally implementation specific

Answer (score 7):

If the GC decides to move an object, it is its responsibility to update all references to that object.

This is transparent to the Java programmer: they can treat a reference as an abstract handle, and not worry about how the JVM manages object storage.

Comment: It's worth noting that even on systems where an object reference holds a physical address, the *meaning* of the object reference is defined purely in terms of what exists at that address, and *the set of all references to address that exist anywhere in the universe*.  If there exist two references to an object at address 0x12345678, copying the data to 0x23456789 and updating both references to point to that new address will leave the state of the program unchanged.  Note that for obvious reasons it's imperative that for every object the GC know about all references everywhere in the universe.

Answer (score 4):

Object references in Java are an abstract concept. They are not just integers representing memory offsets like C++ pointers. The Java Virtual Machine abstracts the access to the object it points to, so you don't have to worry about how the JVM manages its memory internally.

Answer (score -3):

Address doesn't change because the object reference is being moved not the object.

Comment: Really, do you have link to JVM specification that describes this behavior?

Comment: This is nonsense.  In all mainstream JVMs **objects** are moved.